# 'Django Administrator' Title not Changing

Tags: django

I have been following the Django tutorial, but for some reason when I tried to change the 'Django Administrator' title nothing happened.

I copied the base_site.html into a poll/template/admin folder, and changed the `'Django Administrator'` to `'Poll Admin'`.

I also added:
`TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]` to the `admin.py`, and nothing changed.

I even went as far as going into the original template folder and changing that, but again the title remained the  same.

Comment: What is the value of your ``TEMPLATE_LOADERS`` setting ?

Comment: The tutorial said nothing about TEMPLATE_LOADERS, and I do not have it in my settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I put the template directory in the wrong place instead of mysite/templates
I put it in mysite/polls/template.